# Apache Beam Spark Runner Issues

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-beam, spark-submit

We are trying to submit a Spark job through YARN with the following command:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=/path/to/stage  --verbose --class com.my.class --jars /path/to/jar1,path/to/jar2 /path/to/main/jar/application.jar
```

The application is being populated in the YARN scheduler however it never appears to start the Application Master container.  The trace is:

```
17/12/04 11:21:32 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
17/12/04 11:27:16 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkContextFactory.createSparkContext(SparkContextFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkContextFactory.getSparkContext(SparkContextFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:197)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at com.my.class.main(myclass.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/12/04 11:27:16 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
17/12/04 11:27:16 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkContextFactory.createSparkContext(SparkContextFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkContextFactory.getSparkContext(SparkContextFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:197)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at at com.my.class.main(myclass.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

We are able to run the sample Spark Pi job to completion without errors.

Version:

```
$ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-mapr-1703
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_101
```

We think the issue may be with how we are setting up our pipeline:

```
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
```

We run our Pipeline with:

```
p.run(options);
```

The pipeline was running successfully with the DirectRunner.

We made sure to include ***beam-runners-spark*** as a Maven Dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Beam only supports Apache Spark 1.6.3 currently.  We are currently using Apache Spark 2.1 so it is not working.

Comment: any updates on the Apache Beam supported Apache Spark version ?

Comment: the docs say "The Spark runner currently supports Spark’s 2.x branch, and more specifically any version greater than 2.4.0"

see: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/